# Minibuffer size in emacs increasing on changing the default font

Tags: emacs

Hi I was changing my default font in emacs. Suddenly, the size of the minibuffer is becoming huge occupying 1/4 of the screenspace. This happens whenever I change my default font.

How do I correct this? (See Screenshot). I am using Emacs 23.1.1

[image])

Comment: What did you do to change your default font?

Comment: Sounds like a bad font -- maybe it contains some characters that are encoded as much higher than the normal ones. Does this happen with all fonts or only a specific one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a bug. `M-x report-emacs-bug'.

Comment: Hmmm will do that. I got the problem fixed by changing the scroll-bar position from left to right. Strange I know but that's what happened.:D

Comment: Truly sounds like it's worth reporting a bug.  Mention the workaround you found too.